# Wait until attribute changed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Page has a spinner (when page loads)

```
<div id="event-wait-msg-main" style="display: block;">
  <div id="event-wait-msg"></div>
</div>
```

When page is loaded `style` attribute changes to `display: none;`

How can I use `webdriver wait` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait until element will be invisible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "event-wait-msg-main")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom expected condition

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(__WaitForAttributeToBe(By.id('event-wait-msg'), 'style', 'display: none;'))

class __WaitForAttributeToBe(object):
    def __init__(self, by, attribute, expected_value):
        self.__by = by
        self.__attribute = attribute
        self.__expected_value = expected_value

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            attribute_value = driver.find_element(self.__by).get_attribute(self.__attribute)
            return attribute_value == self.__expected_value
        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath, './/div[contains(@style,'none')]')))
```